# DPKG dependencies problem after removing MariaDB, prevents me from using apt-get

Tags: 13.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, mariadb

I tried to install MariaDB [like this](https://askubuntu.com/a/300336/4066), and got this error:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient18_5.5.32+maria-1~raring_amd64.deb (--unpack):  
libmysqlclient18:amd64 5.5.32+maria-1~raring (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with libmysqlclient18 which has multiple installed instances  
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
```

I tried to install mysql-server instead, but got:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 libmariadbclient18 : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.32+maria-1~raring) but 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 is to be installed  
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed  
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`apt-get -f install` does not work, though:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient18_5.5.32+maria-1~raring_amd64.deb (--unpack):  
 libmysqlclient18:amd64 5.5.32+maria-1~raring (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with libmysqlclient18 which has multiple installed instances
```

I tried roll back, so `sudo dpkg -r mariadb-servermariadb-client-core-5.5 mariadb-client-5.5 mariadb-server-core-5.5` which worked. `mariadb-server` is not installed apparently. Then I tried `sudo dpkg -r libmysqlclient18` but got:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libmysqlclient18:amd64:  
 amarok depends on libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.13-1).
```

I don't want to remove amarok as it has been installed for a long time.
How can I solve this error and remove all of MariaDB?

aptitude is not installed, and when I start Ubuntu Software Center it tells me `New software can't be installed, because there is a problem with the software currently installed. Do you want to repair this problem now?`, when I click `Repair` an internal error appears:

[image]

---

As requested, output of `sudo apt-get check`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmariadbclient18 : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.32+maria-1~raring) but 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Output of `apt-cache policy libmysqlclient18 libmariadbclient18`:

```
libmysqlclient18:
  Installed: 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1
  Candidate: 5.5.32+maria-1~raring
  Version table:
     5.5.32+maria-1~raring 0
        500 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 0
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.29-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
libmariadbclient18:
  Installed: 5.5.32+maria-1~raring
  Candidate: 5.5.32+maria-1~raring
  Version table:
 *** 5.5.32+maria-1~raring 0
        500 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)]/ raring main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main

##############################################################
##################### UNOFFICIAL  REPOS http://repogen.simplylinux.ch ######################
##############################################################

###### 3rd Party Binary Repos

#### Google Chrome Browser - http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/
## Run this command: wget -q https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

#### Google Earth - http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/
## Run this command: wget -q https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main

#### Midori PPA - https://launchpad.net/~midori/+archive/ppa
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A69241F1
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu raring main

#### Opera - http://www.opera.com/
## Run this command: sudo wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free

#### Oracle Java (JDK) Installer PPA - http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu raring main

#### VirtualBox - http://www.virtualbox.org
## Run this command: wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian raring contrib

#### X Updates - https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys AF1CDFA9
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu raring main


####### 3rd Party Source Repos

#### Gimp PPA (Source) - https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/gimp
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 614C4B38
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu raring main

#### Midori PPA (Source) - https://launchpad.net/~midori/+archive/ppa
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A69241F1
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu raring main

#### Oracle Java (JDK) Installer PPA (Source) - http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu raring main

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ raring partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ raring partner
deb http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu raring main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu raring main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bhdouglass/indicator-remindor/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/bhdouglass/indicator-remindor/ubuntu raring main
deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu raring main
```

Comment: @Braiam: Added.

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy libmysqlclient18 libmariadbclient18` and the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`?

Comment: Ok, now you want to delete MariaDB (the title now suggest that) or repair the package dependencies?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you almost got it. Remove the MariaDB packages:

`dpkg -r mariadb-servermariadb-client-core-5.5 mariadb-client-5.5 mariadb-server-core-5.5 libmariadbclient18`

Now remove the `deb http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu raring main` line from your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Next make sure the MySql package from the MariaDB aren't still in the cache:

`apt-get clean`

Finally, reinstall `libmysqlclient18`:

`apt-get install --reinstall libmysqlclient18`

Comment: I get: `dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove mariadb-servermariadb-client-core-5.5 which isn't installed
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove mariadb-client-5.5, only the config
 files of which are on the system; use --purge to remove them too
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove mariadb-server-core-5.5 which isn't installed`. Anyway I proceeded: removed from sources.list, apt-get clean, but apt-get install --reinstall libmysqlclient18 fails: `The following packages have unmet dependencies: libmariadbclient18 : Depends: libmysqlclient18`

Comment: you also need to remove libmariadbclient18, with `dpkg -r libmariadbclient18`.  then apt-get clean and apt-get install.  if you see more warnings about other maria-specific packages then remove them too.

Comment: That worked! I also had to do `dpkg -r mariadb-client-core-5.5`. Well-deserved bounty!

Comment: worked for me on ubuntu 14.04 raring, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
```

then try to do what you were trying to do.let me know what you got.

Comment: Output of `sudo apt-get check`: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmariadbclient18 : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.32+maria-1~raring) but 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Comment: Output of `sudo apt-get autoremove`: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmariadbclient18 : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.32+maria-1~raring) but 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all the dependency package from synaptic package manager. And use 'aptitude' to install packages instead of apt-get.

Here's why:
[aptitude-vs-apt-get](https://superuser.com/questions/93437/aptitude-vs-apt-get-which-is-the-recommended-aka-the-right-tool-to-use)

I'm guessing it's an issue with the apt-get.

Comment: I can't install `aptitude` nor `synaptic` nor anything. Also, Ubuntu Software Center won't start (internal error, added screenshot).

Comment: I remember I had the same problem. Have you tried building and installing aptitude from source code? [link](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/pr01s04s02.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue. Is just not possible. You have packages that depends on the `5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1` version of `libmysqlclient18` while `libmariadbclient18` depends on `5.5.32+maria-1~raring`.

The solution, either delete the packages that depends of the `5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1` version with `sudo apt-get -f autoremove libmysqlclient18` (**NOT RECOMENDABLE**) or tell **the package maintainer to fix their stuff** because is impossible to install it without breaking the system. How I know?

In the long list of 152 packages there are a "critical" packages that depends of that specific version of `libmysqlclient18` hence apt-get reuses to delete it and provokes this mayor breakages.

Inform the packages maintainers to fix their stuff correctly.

If you want to know which package is use:

```
apt-cache rdepends libmysqlclient18=5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1
```

Will tell you the packages that has an implicit dependency of that version, then you only need to compare with a list of your installed packages and voila!

Comment: Thanks but it outputs an error: `libmysqlclient18:amd64 5.5.32+maria-1~raring (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with libmysqlclient18 which has multiple installed instances`

Comment: `apt-cache rdepends libmysqlclient18` tells me I have 152 packages that depend on it :-/

Comment: Is it normal that libmysqlclient18 depends on libmariadbclient18?

Comment: I got the answer... but you won't like it...

Comment: Any solution is better than not being able to install any new software :-)

Comment: Well, uninstalling that package you will be able to use any software... but that one... BTW, I think you should delete previous comments since, they lost relevance ;)

Comment: Could you explicit what you meant by "I got the answer"? What is it exactly?

Comment: The package breaks the system due the poor maintaining. You should contact the package provider so they solve their stuff.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10658/discussion-between-braiam-and-nicolas-raoul)