# dpkg is broken, how to recover?

Tags: 13.04, dpkg, multiarch

When I ran `apt-get`, the system said that dpkg is broken, use `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to recover, but when I ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, it showed the following error message:

```
dpkg: error: liboil0.3:amd64 0.3.16-1ubuntu2 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with liboil0.3 which has multiple installed instances
```

How do I fix this? Please help.

Comment: i manually edited the file under /var/lib/dpkg/available and status, remove the dublicated liboil0.3 section and `dpkg` work now.

Comment: this [link](http://superuser.com/questions/22110/how-to-fix-broken-synaptic-updates-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state/210764#210764) help me a lot. Thanks @Avinash Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was the reason behind this error means,you are trying to install 64 bit version of `liboil0.3`,but your system has already installed a 32-bit version of `liboil0.3`.Run the below command in terminal to fix this problem.

```
sudo dpkg -r liboil0.3:i386
```

Comment: if there any error occurs post here.

Comment: the error is:
    $ sudo dpkg -r liboil0.3:i386
    [sudo] password for xxxxx: 
    dpkg: error: liboil0.3:amd64 0.3.16-1ubuntu2 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with liboil0.3 which has multiple installed instances

Comment: Try the above command only.and post the output.

Comment: please reply fast.

Comment: open `synaptic package manager`,search for liboil0.3 and uninstall it.Then run  `apt-get` command.

Comment: above is the output message

`sudo dpkg -r liboil0.3:i386`

it steady show the message

`dpkg: error: liboil0.3:amd64 0.3.16-1ubuntu2 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with liboil0.3 which has multiple installed instances `

`synaptic package manager`
not work properly, i can't remove any software. I think the error is the same.

Comment: when I open synaptic package manager, it says

`E: dpkg 被中断，您必须手工运行 dpkg --configure -a 解决此问题。`
`E: _cache->open() failed, please report.`

when I manually run the command `dpkg --configure -a` it shows the message
dpkg: error: liboil0.3:amd64 0.3.16-1ubuntu2 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with liboil0.3 which has multiple installed instances

Comment: see this page,it would so helpful to solve your problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/343232/dpkg-dependencies-problem-after-removing-mariadb-prevents-me-from-using-apt-get