# Problems during installation of MariaDb on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, mariadb

I'm trying to install MariaDB according to this documentation:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://mirrors.fe.up.pt/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu precise main'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

But faced with problem which is solved at this [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365992/ubuntu-13-10-installing-mariadb)
I'm using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server-5.5="5.5.33a+maria-1~saucy" 
mariadb-client 5.5="5.5.33a+maria-1~saucy" \libmysqlclient18="5.5.33a+maria-1~saucy" 
    \mysql-common="5.5.33a+maria-1~saucy"
```

Intead of saucy I've wrote precise but it doesn't help, I'm getting such errors:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Note, selecting 'mariadb-galera-server-5.5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'mariadb-test-5.5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-simpleea-dev-0.1.1-a1525' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'hl5150dlpr' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-haskelldb-prof-2.1.1-5a57e' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libassa3.5-5-dbg' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libassa3.5-5-dev' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'sword-text-gerlut1545' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-5.5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-5.5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-core-5.5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'cupswrapperhl5150d' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-http-conduit-prof-1.2.5-502c3' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-hdbc-sqlite3-prof-2.3.3.0-fe5b5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-leksah-server-dev-0.12.0.4-45c55' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-core-5.5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-hdbc-sqlite3-dev-2.3.3.0-fe5b5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-primitive-dev-0.4.1-50546' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-haskelldb-dev-2.1.1-5a57e' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-simpleea-prof-0.1.1-a1525' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'u-boot-linaro-smdk5250' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-void-prof-0.5.5-f4fcb' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libassa3.5-5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'netbeans5.5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'handlersocket-mysql-5.5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-void-dev-0.5.5-f4fcb' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-http-conduit-dev-1.2.5-502c3' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-bifunctors-prof-0.1.2-5156d' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'hl5050lpr' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-ansi-terminal-prof-0.5.5-3c75c' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-yesod-json-dev-0.3.1-85953' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'solr-tomcat5.5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'cupswrapperhl5250dn' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-mime-mail-prof-0.4.1.1-ee5a5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libvirtuoso5.5-cil' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libxmlplaylist-ocaml-dev-iq545' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-bifunctors-dev-0.1.2-5156d' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-mime-mail-dev-0.4.1.1-ee5a5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-5.5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-primitive-prof-0.4.1-50546' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'mysql-source-5.5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-yesod-json-prof-0.3.1-85953' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'cupswrapperhl5050' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'libghc-ansi-terminal-dev-0.5.5-3c75c' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'brhl5250dnlpr' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'cupswrapperfax5750e' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.5' for regex '5.5'
    Note, selecting 'fax5750elpr' for regex '5.5'
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'mysql-server-core-5.5' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'mysql-client-core-5.5' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'mysql-client-5.5' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'mysql-server-5.5' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libassa3.5-5' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'handlersocket-mysql-5.5' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libassa3.5-5-dbg' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libassa3.5-5-dev' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-void-dev-0.5.5-f4fcb' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-void-prof-0.5.5-f4fcb' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-ansi-terminal-dev-0.5.5-3c75c' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-ansi-terminal-prof-0.5.5-3c75c' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-http-conduit-dev-1.2.5-502c3' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-http-conduit-prof-1.2.5-502c3' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-bifunctors-dev-0.1.2-5156d' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-bifunctors-prof-0.1.2-5156d' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-primitive-dev-0.4.1-50546' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-primitive-prof-0.4.1-50546' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-haskelldb-dev-2.1.1-5a57e' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-haskelldb-prof-2.1.1-5a57e' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-hdbc-sqlite3-dev-2.3.3.0-fe5b5' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-hdbc-sqlite3-prof-2.3.3.0-fe5b5' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-leksah-server-dev-0.12.0.4-45c55' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-mime-mail-dev-0.4.1.1-ee5a5' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-mime-mail-prof-0.4.1.1-ee5a5' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-simpleea-dev-0.1.1-a1525' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-simpleea-prof-0.1.1-a1525' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-yesod-json-dev-0.3.1-85953' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libghc-yesod-json-prof-0.3.1-85953' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libxmlplaylist-ocaml-dev-iq545' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'libvirtuoso5.5-cil' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'solr-tomcat5.5' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'mysql-source-5.5' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'mysql-testsuite-5.5' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'netbeans5.5' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'sword-text-gerlut1545' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'cupswrapperhl5250dn' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'cupswrapperfax5750e' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'cupswrapperhl5050' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'cupswrapperhl5150d' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'brhl5250dnlpr' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'fax5750elpr' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'hl5050lpr' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'hl5150dlpr' was not found
    E: Version '5.5.33a+maria-1~precise' for 'u-boot-linaro-smdk5250' was not found
```

How can I fix it and install MariaDb?

Comment: did you try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/64772/how-to-install-mariadb

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, it was not working for me :( I've installed MariaDB 10

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to install it:

```
sudo aptitude install mariadb-server libmysqlclient18=5.5.33a+maria-1~precise mysql-common=5.5.33a+maria-1~precise
```