# importing mysql backup into a mariaDB instance on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I just installed mariaDB on an ubuntu box using the command:

```
 sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

per the documentation found here: [How to install MariaDB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64772/how-to-install-mariadb)

I have a .sql file that was created on a mysql database server using the command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p"password" --all-databases > "/var/backups/dbs_$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S').sql"
```

Can I just use the sql file as is to import somehow into mariaDB?  Reason I ask is that I see inside the sql file that there's references to the engine type, like this:

```
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Column privileges';
```

Should I just be able run the sql file from the command line?

Comment: Yes, basically MySQL = MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the file because MariaDB supports the MyISAM storage engine: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/myisam-storage-engine/

You get the list of all supported storage engines by invoking `SHOW ENGINES`: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/show-engines/