# How to manually upgrade MariaDB 10.6.7 to 10.6.11

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates, 22.04, mariadb

I have had MariaDB installed on my server for a while now. I previously used `sudo apt install mariadb-server` to install.

I wish to upgrade this to 10.6.11 as this is the newest stable LTS version, but the Ubuntu distro only has 10.6.7 and won't allow me to upgrade using `apt upgrade mariadb-server`.

I have tried removing the server using `apt remove mariadb-server`, then adding the repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,arm64,ppc64el] https://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.6/ubuntu focal main'
```

... then installing, but it's a big ole mess.  Even after the `apt remove`, the server was still there.  I did an apt purge and got rid of it, but when i try an `apt install mariadb-server`, I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: lists mariabd-server
```

And then quits. Obviously, I don't know what I'm doing.

I'd appreciate a step-by-step how to upgrade MariaDB beyond what's natively available in the Ubuntu distro.

Comment: As you probably found out, it's a bad idea to mess with the default versions on Ubuntu, unless you know what you're doing. Also, [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software).

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to do this upgrade? If you know how it would be helpful to share what the steps are to complete the upgrade. Rather than just a warning to "not mess with stuff you don't know about"

Comment: I don't know any way with no risk of breaking the system. And it seems there are [no PPA's](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=mariadb) for this version. Is there any particular reason you can't use the version provided with Ubuntu?

Comment: as if by magic, 22.04 distro now contains MariaDB 10.6.11

Comment: Yeah, the Ubuntu universe team "magically" [updated to 10.6.11](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/m/mariadb-10.6/mariadb-10.6_10.6.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1/changelog).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install MariaDB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64772/how-to-install-mariadb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways of installing MariaDB on Ubuntu 22.04 - from the Universe repo, or from the MariaDB repo.

###### 1. Via Universe repo

The Ubuntu Universe team has [updated `mariadb` to 10.6.11](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/m/mariadb-10.6/mariadb-10.6_10.6.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1/changelog).
Make sure the following lines are uncommented in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
```

Then run `sudo apt install mariadb-server`. Note that the Universe repo might be slower to implement security patches than the MariaDB repo - so some months may pass before an update hits this repo.

###### 2. Via MariaDB official repo

Customize your repo configuration [this page](https://mariadb.org/download/?t=repo-config).

With the following selected:

- Distribution: 22.04 (Jammy)
- MariaDB version: 10.6
- Mirror: LiquidTelecom (Nairobi)

Run the following to add the repo:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https curl
sudo curl -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mariadb_release_signing_key.asc 'https://mariadb.org/mariadb_release_signing_key.asc'
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb https://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.6/ubuntu jammy main' >>/etc/apt/sources.list"
```

Now you can run the following to install the latest version:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mariadb-server
```

This version will likely be patched more often than the Universe provided version.

It should also be possible to add the MariaDB repo, and then run `sudo apt upgrade` to switch over to any newer version in the MariaDB repos.